# Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found Even if php-mongo has been installed

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, php-mongodb

Since I was using MongoDB as the app's database, I have installed MongoDB and `jessenger/laravel-mongodb` by composer to the app.

After setting up, I get the error

```
FatalErrorException in Client.php line 81:
Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found
```

But I'm sure it have installed all the requirements.

Mongo has been installed.

```
$ mongo --version
MongoDB shell version v3.4.0
```

PHP Mongo driver has been installed as well

```
$ brew install php55-mongodb
Warning: homebrew/php/php55-mongodb-1.2.5 already installed
```

See what the ini file is loaded, appears that `ext-mongo` exists in `/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/` folder.

```
$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/5.5
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-mcrypt.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-mongo.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-mongodb.ini
```

And finally, `phpinfo()` doesn't find any words about `mongo` (Not be loaded?)

Questions are:

1. Should I add `extension=` to the `php.ini` file? If so, what is the correct extension name for OS X? (and how to find them?)

   *(I've tried to do that with whatever `extension=mongo.so`, `mongo.dll` or `mongodb.so` and other possibilities. Does not work.)*
2. `phpinfo()` doesn't show any about `mongo`, that means PHP mongo drivers were not installed correctly? How to deal with that? Add `extension=` to the file?
3. Did I lost something unconcernedly?

I spent much time. Any answers would save my time. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't solve the problem eventually. But I removed built-in `apache2` and `PHP` then reinstalled them by `brew` instead. This time I chose `apache24` and `php70`, also turned to `php70-mongodb` rather than 5.5's.

By the way, I'm sure that is the problem caused by the package not being installed correctly or setting wrong. But I didn't solve problem toward that way. I chose another (install other versions) instead.

#### 1. Remove built-in apache

Let apache stop

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

Remove built-in apache

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist 2>/dev/null
```

#### 2. Install packages by Homebrew

Install apache (apache is called `httpd`)

```
brew install httpd24
```

Install php 7

```
brew install php70 --with-apache
```

Install PHP driver of MongoDB

```
brew install php70-mongodb --with-apache
```

#### 3. Restart apache

```
sudo apachectl restart
```